# Why does the CheckinEvent SOAP message from the TFS event service only contain the first 25 files in the changeset?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using **bissubscribe.exe** to subscribe to events published by our Team Foundation Server (2010).

When receiving the SOAP message from TFS for the **CheckinEvent** event type, it only includes the first 25 versioned item changes even though I know there were more files changed.

I can't find this restriction documented anywhere on MSDN (in fact the TFS eventing service documentation seems to be largely limited to [this post from 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be by design.  I couldn't find any specific reference to this in any documentation, but there is a [comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/29/checkinevent-path-filter.aspx#9185062) and [response](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/29/checkinevent-path-filter.aspx#9185767) on a Buck Hodges [blog entry from 2006](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/29/checkinevent-path-filter.aspx) that explains:

> You'll need to use the `GetChangeset()` method on the
>   `VersionControlServer` object to get all of the changes.  We limit the
>   number in the XML to prevent it from being a memory problem with
>   extremely large checkins.

So in summary, if you really need *all* versioned item changes, on receiving the notification you will need to make a separate call to [GetChangeset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138627(v=vs.100).aspx).